# Write data to csv, then overwrite after certain amount of lines has been entered

Tags: php, api, csv, export-to-csv

I am in the process of writing an API for a client. 
They want to be able to view 14 days worth of sales data on a webpage. 
Unfortunately, the api for the program he is using is limited, but has allowed me to get the current days sales of the item. 
What my initial thought was, to record and write the SKU, Total Sales and the Value of sales to a csv like so:

sku, total, value
sku, total, value
sku, total, value

etc
etc

Is there a way so that after 14 lines of data have been entered into this csv, to write into the php so that it then rewrites over the first line, then the second line, then the third, without deleting the remaining data?
I was thinking maybe to do a count for the amount of lines, if it is less than 14, continue writing, if it is equal to 14, write over. I am not sure this is possible, or even how to go about this, i'm pretty new to PHP.

Many thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### FIRST (count lines)

```
$file="URL_FOR_YOUR_CSV_FILE.csv";
$linecount = 0;
$handle = fopen($file, "r");

while(!feof($handle)){
  $line = fgets($handle, 4096);
  $linecount = $linecount + substr_count($line, PHP_EOL);
}
fclose($handle);
```

### SECOND (clean file)

```
if ($linecount >= 14) {
  file_put_contents("URL_FOR_YOUR_CSV_FILE.csv", "");
}
```

### WRITE AGAIN